# Unhandled Runtime Error Error: fetch failed Call Stack Object.fetch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, strapi, next.js13, headless

The following code does not work, However i dont know what i did wrong.

```
import Image from "next/image";
import config from "@/lib/config";

const fetchPosts = async () => {
  const requestOptions = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  };
  const request = await fetch(
    `${config.api}api/posts?populate=*`,
    requestOptions
  );
  const response = await request.json();
  return response;
};

const Home = async () => {
  const posts = await fetchPosts();
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="p-5 bg-primary">Hello</div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

in my lib/config just an api

```
const config = {
  api: "http://localhost:1337/",
};
export default config;
```

I am using next js 13.5 with typescript. for the backend I am using strapi and i already test it with postman I do receive data from the GET request.

Comment: What is the full error from Next.js?

Comment: The problem is that I don't get a full error. The only error which is displayed is the one I have written in the title of my question.